# Source object must be a surface

Tags: python, pygame

I am encountering a problem which says that the source object must be a surface. I asked this question before, and the answer worked, but now it's a different scenario. I looked at the previous question I had, and I couldn't figure out how to solve it.

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Thing.py", line 22, in <module>
level.run()
File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\level2.py", line 131, in run
self.clouds.draw(self.display_surface, self.world_shift)
File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\decoration.py", line 67, in draw
self.cloud_sprites.draw(surface)
File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 551, in draw
self.spritedict.update(zip(sprites, surface.blits((spr.image, spr.rect) for 
spr in sprites)))
TypeError: Source objects must be a surface
```

Basically I am trying to blit things onto a surface, and the thing that confuses me the most is that it worked when I was trying to blit water onto the screen, it had the exact same code but instead of 'cloud' it had 'water', however the water blitting worked while the cloud did not.

Water Class:

```
class Water:
def __init__(self, top, level_width):
    water_start = -width
    water_tile_width = 192
    tile_x_amount = int((level_width + width) / water_tile_width)
    self.water_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

    for tile in range(tile_x_amount):
        x = tile * water_tile_width + water_start
        y = top
        sprite = AnimatedTile(192, x, y, (x, y), 
        'C:\\Desktop\\Game\\decoration\\water')
        self.water_sprites.add(sprite)


def draw(self, surface, shift):
    self.water_sprites.update(shift)
    self.water_sprites.draw(surface)
```

Cloud Class:

```
class Clouds:
def __init__(self, horizon, level_width, cloud_number):
    min_x = -width
    max_x = level_width + width 
    min_y = 0
    max_y = horizon
    cloud_surface_list = 'C:\\Desktop\\Game\\decoration\\clouds'
    self.cloud_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

    for cloud in range(cloud_number):
        cloud = choice(cloud_surface_list)
        x = randint(min_x, max_x)
        y = randint(min_y, max_y)
        sprite = StaticTile(0, x, y, (x, y), 
        'C:\\Desktop\\Game\\decoration\\clouds')
        self.cloud_sprites.add(sprite)

def draw(self, surface, shift):
    self.cloud_sprites.update(shift)
    self.cloud_sprites.draw(surface)
```

As you can see the draw method is the exact same code, pretty much. The only difference that I can spot that could be causing the problem would be the inheritance. `Water` inherits from a class called `AnimatedTile` while `Clouds` inherits from `StaticTile`. I will put the code for both of those here:

AnimatedTile:

```
class AnimatedTile(Tile):
def __init__(self, size, x, y, pos, path):
    super().__init__(size, x, y, (x, y))
    self.frames = import_folder(path)
    self.frame_index = 0
    self.image = self.frames[int(self.frame_index)]

def animate(self):
    self.frame_index += 0.15

    if self.frame_index >= 4:
        self.frame_index = 0

    self.image = self.frames[int(self.frame_index)]

def update(self, shift):
    self.animate()
    self.rect.x += shift
```

StaticTile:

```
class StaticTile(Tile):
def __init__(self, size, x, y, pos, surface):
    super().__init__(size, x, y, (x,y))
    self.image = surface
    self.surface = surface
```

Drawing and Updating:

```
self.clouds.draw(self.display_surface, 
self.world_shift)
```

*I know these are surfaces because I drew them the same exact way to blit the water onto the screen (`self.water.draw(self.display_surface, self.world_shift)` and it worked.

Other code:

```
class Level:
    def __init__(self, level_data, surface):

        self.display_surface = surface
        self.world_shift = -8
```

Tile:

```
class Tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, size, x, y, pos):
    super().__init__()
    self.image = pygame.Surface((size, size))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)

def update(self, shift):
    self.rect.x += shift
```

`world_shift` is basically how fast the level is moving (negative means right, positive means left)

I'm sorry if this sounds stupid and the answer is obvious.

Comment: error shows you in which line is problem - `self.clouds.draw(self.display_surface, self.world_shift)` - so first you could use `print()`, `print(type(..))` to check what you have in variables in this line. I don't see this line in code in question so I can't say what can be problem but it seems one of them is NOT surface.

Comment: @furas -- I know that one of them is a surface because I did the exact same code to draw the water as I did to draw the cloud and it worked (I edited the question so the code you're asking for is there)

Comment: maybe in other code you used surface but in current code you could make mistake - so don't trust yourself and check variables.

Comment: in new code I still don't see where you create variables `self.display_surface` and `self.world_shift` and I can't say if you assign correct values.

Comment: another question - what is `self.water` and `self.coulds`? are they single sprites or groups? Group may need different values then single Sprite.

Comment: they are both `pygame.sprite.Group()`

Comment: we can't see full code, we can't run it - I can only suggest to use `print()`,`print(type())` to check variables and see which part of code is executed. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing. Maybe some code assign something different to variables and this makes problem. Don't trust your code and check everything.

Comment: @furas when I print self.display_surface it prints `<Surface(1280x720x32 SW)>` and when I print type it says `<class 'pygame.Surface'>`

Comment: You have asked the same question some days ago [Source object must be a surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71506805/pygame-sprite-drawing-on-surface-issue)

Comment: yes but I looked at that one and couldn't figure out an answer based on that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not correctly assigning to the `image` attribute of your `StaticTile` sprite in `Clouds`. I'm not sure if it's the caller (`Clouds`) or the tile class that is getting it wrong though, you'll have to decide what the API should be.

The mismatch is between your call, here:

```
sprite = StaticTile(0, x, y, (x, y), 
    'C:\\Desktop\\Game\\decoration\\clouds')
```

And the `StaticTile.__init__` method, which is declared like this:

```
def __init__(self, size, x, y, pos, surface):
    super().__init__(size, x, y, (x,y))
    self.image = surface
    self.surface = surface
```

Note that the calling code is passing a string as the `surface` argument. That's similar to how `AnimatedTile` is initialized (with a path), but the `StaticTile` class expects a surface object to already be loaded.

Comment: So what should I put instead of the path?

Comment: Probably `pygame.image.load(path)`? I'm not sure how your `AnimatedTile` class does it because you have a separate function that loads things for that one. Maybe you have an image loading function too?

Comment: ok -- added the code for 'Tile' into the question

Comment: @Daniel I agree with Blckknght - you send path but `StaticTile` expect surface, and you could use `self.image pygame.image.load(surface)` or you should load image before you send to `StaticTile`. BTW: I see another problem with `path`. You assign path `cloud_surface_list = 'C:\\...` and late you do `choice(cloud_surface_list)` but it will NOT select file from folder but char from string `C:\\...` (but lucky, later you don't even use this `cloud` so it doesn't raise error)